# JWT Authentication .Net core [Authorize] Attribute Ignored by Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to implement JWT based authentication in my App that has an Angular 8 Frontend and .Net Core Backend. I have added

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

and

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
```

in the startup class.I have decorated the controller method using the `[Authorize]` attribute. But when i try to hit the controller method without any tokens it allows entry into the controller method.

**StartUp**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
     
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var jwtSettings = Configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings");
            services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.GetSection("validIssuer").Value,
                    ValidAudience = jwtSettings.GetSection("validAudience").Value,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.GetSection("securityKey").Value))
                };
            });
            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            // requires using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
            services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(
                Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DatabaseSettings)));

            services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
                sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseSettings>>().Value);

            services.AddSingleton<FileService>();

            services.AddSingleton<InternalReportService>();


            services.AddTransient<MailService>();
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseMvc();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();          
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();             

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<CoreHub>("/corehub");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                  
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
public async Task UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
// Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: try use  this services.AddMvcCore() instead of services.AddMvc()

Comment: You did not share code that creates the JWT or persists the token.

Comment: `https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-1/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Your authentication scheme, You should specify attribute this way:
`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]`
and this should work as You expect

Comment: Thanks ... but this does not work.

Comment: @techno can you provide full code of your controller?

Comment: The issue is sorted.I was hitting the wrong method.

Comment: @techno Do You mean that some of answers was correct? Or You mean that whole question wasn't about problem?

Comment: Adding Bearer actually fixed the issue. But the real problem was something else.

Answer (score 9):

Well, you have configured the authentication part of your API, now you need to configure the authorization the same way...

You can configure like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Default", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build());

    options.AddPolicy("Admin", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireRole("Admin")
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build());
});
```

Then you will be able to use the attribute as

```
[Authorize("User")]
[Authorize("Admin")]
```

on your controllers or specific endpoints.

If you wish to put this default policy on all your endpoints/controllers and control only the "AllowAnonymous" part of if, you can do this:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            // Mark all endpoints with the default policy
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("Default"));
        })
```

Comment: Should be the correct answer.

Comment: Why is it mandatory to define roles? My application only needs valid Token to function,there is no need for roles.

Comment: You dont **need** a role, just define a default -no named- policy, as @GibbOne already showed using  `opts.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(opts.DefaultPolicy).RequireAuthenticatedUser()`, in fact you can use both if you want, the same is applied to the global filter

Comment: In fact, the default policy is static, just calling `services.AddAuthorization()` should work i guess, otherwise youll have to configure it

Answer (score 1):

I usually add `DefaultSchema`.

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
//...
```

and authorization.

```
services.AddAuthorization(opts =>
{
    opts.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(opts.DefaultPolicy)
          .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
//...
```